# What to do with the (subspaces) tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There is a tag called [subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subspaces). (It seems that it was created by [this user](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=102540).) Both tag-wiki and tag-excerpt are currently empty, so the usage is unclear.<sup>1</sup> If we consider just the name of the tag, there are plenty of situations where it can be used: vector spaces, topological spaces, metric spaces, normed spaces, ... At the moment there are 53 questions having this tag. Majority seems to be about subspaces of vector spaces.

It seems that we have basically two options:

- Use this tag as a kind of "meta tag" - the meaning will be clear from other tags added.
- Specify for which of the possible meanings it should be used. (Although in that case it would probably be good to rename tag to something more descriptive.)

---

I will mention that some similar tags have been discussed -- I mean various tags related to creating new structures from old ones, where the particular construction is applicable to various types of structures.

- Creating [products-abstract](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/products-abstract) for products of various types of structures was proposed here: [What should be in (products) tag?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20620/what-should-be-in-products-tag/20842#20842)
- Tag [quotient-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotient-spaces) was discussed here: [What is the tag (quotient-spaces) intended for?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17531/what-is-the-tag-quotient-spaces-intended-for)
- There <s>are</s> were tags [direct-limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/direct-limit) and [inverse-limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inverse-limits); see here: [Tag management 2015](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015/21041#21041) (It seems that the later has been removed shortly after I made this post: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/38517/revisions), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1342987/revisions), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1362299/revisions), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1388100/revisions). The former was removed a bit later: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/683703/revisions),
  [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/792430/revisions),
  [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/869839/revisions),
  [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1342601/revisions),
  [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1342760/revisions),
  [6](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1343070/revisions),
  [7](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1373404/revisions),
  [8](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1380030/revisions).)
- There exists also the tag [limits-colimits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits-colimits), created after the discussion [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20700). However, it seems to have category-theoretic flavour, so using it for products, quotient spaces, subspaces and similar stuff seems like a stretch if there is no category theory involved.

---

<sup>1</sup>In the meantime, [the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/subspaces/info) has been added. The current wording seems to suggest that the tag is for vector subspaces. (I will also add link to the [revision history of the tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1688971/revisions) and [the same for the tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1688970/revisions).)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Update.** The [subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subspaces) tag has been removed thanks to a friendly neighbourhood Community Manager.

There's another possibility that hasn't been mentioned in the OP, and the one I would prefer: kill it!

I don't see [subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subspaces) as a tag that will ever be consistently used, and not something that has a concrete enough meaning to allow for an easy delineation of when it *should* be used. Should you apply the tag if you are asking about a specific subspace of some specific ambient space (*e.g.*, "Does this subspace $Y$ of $X$ have property $\mathfrak{P}$?")? Should you apply the tag if you are asking about types of subspaces of some specific ambient space (*e.g.*, "Does $X$ have a subspace having property $\mathfrak{P}$?")? Should it be used when you are talking about the general notion (*e.g.*, "How do you test that something is a subspace?")? I feel that these sorts of questions have about an equal likelihood of ever being given the [subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subspaces) tag, but have vastly different connections to the concept itself. (I feel that these types are listed in more-or-less increasing connection to the concept.)

Even if it were [vector-subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-subspaces) or [topological-subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topological-subspaces), I wouldn't be much in favour of the tag.

(And I'd say we should kill a number of the tags mentioned in the OP.)

Comment: By "kill it" you mean removing the tag from all questions or do you want even to blacklist it.

Comment: I agree that I would definitely prefer two separate tags (or more if needed) to having only one tag. Let's wait to see how other users vote on your post and what they say in the comments - based on this we can take some action.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Simple removal would be fine for now. If it becomes a recurring problem, then a blacklist might be appropriate. But there's no need to involve CMs at this moment.

Comment: About last sentence: *I'd say we should kill a number of the tags mentioned in the OP.* Would it perhaps be better to make a new question to discuss this type of tags in general? (I suppose it is more-or-less clear what is mean by "this type of tags". Having one post about the general issue would probably be better than the current situation - we have several post about various tags which are, to some extent, of the same nature.) This is a digression from the original topic, so perhaps we may continue this discussion [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740) (if needed).

Comment: Where are we on the burnination of this tag?